# JavaFX Application name

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, java-web-start, jnlp

I developed an app using JavaFX2 and generated a jnlp for it. Everything works fine. There is just one small thing that irritates me. When I run the jnlp, it pops up a warning window asking if I want to run the application. So far so good. Name, Publisher, Location and some warning text is visible in the popup window. Publisher and Location have the right corresponding text (i.e. company name and the website) but Name has the value of "com/favafx/main/Main". I've checked and name and the title fields ARE there in the jnlp file with the appropriate text.

I tried to make several JavaFX2 sample apps too and they have the same problem. It seems there's some issue with Javafx2? Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: This is unlikely to be related to JavaFX. Can you show the relevant sections of the jnlp?

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/), but note that I've never been able to locate a DTD or XSD that covers what a Java-FX JNLP (which defines new elements) should look like - so some of the reported errors might be erroneous.  As to the specific problem, make sure the [`information` section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#information) includes a `title` element.

Comment: It was the manifest problem as pointed out by Sebastian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Java 7 update 45, the Manifest has a "security" attribute that is called `Application-Name`. If this attribute is not set, the main class is the name. The main class of every javafx application that is deployed is com.javafx.main.Main. So that explains that.

Read:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u45-relnotes-2016950.html

Obvious solution: add manifest attribute `Application-Name` to your build process.

Comment: "Titles are not shown for unsigned RIAs" -- bummer.